# ¿Cómo establecer NameSpace en documento XML creado desde código C#?

Tags: c#, xml

Desarrollo una aplicación donde genero un documento XML desde código, en estos momentos los NameSpace  se ven de esta manera:

```
<xs:FacturaElectronica xmlns:xs="https://tribunet.hacienda.go.cr/docs/esquemas/2017/v4.2/facturaElectronica">
```

Pero en realidad necesito que se van de esta manera:

```
<FacturaElectronica xmlns:xs="https://tribunet.hacienda.go.cr/docs/esquemas/2017/v4.2/facturaElectronica" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

Mi Código:

```
public void CrearDocumentoXml()
{
 string UrlFacturaELectronica = "https://tribunet.hacienda.go.cr/docs/esquemas/2017/v4.2/facturaElectronica";
                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                XmlDeclaration xmlDeclaracion = xmlDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0","UTF-8",null);
                XmlElement FacturaElectronica = xmlDoc.CreateElement("xs", "FacturaElectronica", UrlFacturaELectronica);
                xmlDoc.AppendChild(FacturaElectronica);
                xmlDoc.InsertBefore(xmlDeclaracion, FacturaElectronica);

                //ENCABEZADO
                XmlElement clave = xmlDoc.CreateElement("xs", "clave", UrlFacturaELectronica);
                clave.InnerText = mClave;
                XmlElement consecutivo = xmlDoc.CreateElement("xs", "consecutivo", UrlFacturaELectronica);
                consecutivo.InnerText = numeroConsecutivo ;
                XmlElement FechaEmision = xmlDoc.CreateElement("xs", "FechaEmision", UrlFacturaELectronica);
                FechaEmision.InnerText = FechaUtc(DateTime.Now);
                FacturaElectronica.AppendChild(clave);
                FacturaElectronica.AppendChild(consecutivo);
                FacturaElectronica.AppendChild(FechaEmision);

   xmlDoc.Save(directorio + nombrArchivo);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Se deben especificar atributos al nodo raiz en este caso (FacturaElectronica)
agregando estas lineas

```
 FacturaElectronica.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
 FacturaElectronica.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
```

El codigo completo:

```
public void CrearDocumentoXml()
{
  string UrlFacturaELectronica = "https://tribunet.hacienda.go.cr/docs/esquemas/2017/v4.2/facturaElectronica";
                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                XmlDeclaration xmlDeclaracion = xmlDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0","UTF-8",null);
                XmlElement FacturaElectronica = xmlDoc.CreateElement("xs", "FacturaElectronica", UrlFacturaELectronica);
                FacturaElectronica.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
                FacturaElectronica.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
                xmlDoc.AppendChild(FacturaElectronica);
                xmlDoc.InsertBefore(xmlDeclaracion, FacturaElectronica);

                //ENCABEZADO
                XmlElement clave = xmlDoc.CreateElement("xs", "clave", UrlFacturaELectronica);
                clave.InnerText = mClave;
                XmlElement consecutivo = xmlDoc.CreateElement("xs", "consecutivo", UrlFacturaELectronica);
                consecutivo.InnerText = numeroConsecutivo ;
                XmlElement FechaEmision = xmlDoc.CreateElement("xs", "FechaEmision", UrlFacturaELectronica);
                FechaEmision.InnerText = FechaUtc(DateTime.Now);
                FacturaElectronica.AppendChild(clave);
                FacturaElectronica.AppendChild(consecutivo);
                FacturaElectronica.AppendChild(FechaEmision);

   xmlDoc.Save(directorio + nombrArchivo);

}
```

para mayor referencia:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920142/how-to-add-xmlnamespace-to-a-xmldocument